# R - create new column with different calculations in each row

Tags: r, datatable, tidyverse

I have been searching extensively but wasn't able to find a solution.

I have a data frame (df) that looks like this:

```
    variable   2014    2015
1      a         3       4     
2      b         2       1
3      c         0       3
4      d         2       3
```

I want to create a new column which uses the 2014 and 2015 columns and does the following calculations:

```
    variable   2014    2015    Bundled
1      a         3       4      3+4=7 
2      b         2       1      2+1=3
3      c         0       2      7/3=2.33
4      d         2       3      (3*2 + 4*3)/7
```

The last calculation is essentially

```
    (df[1,2]*df[4,2] + df[1,3]*df[4,3])/df[1,4]
```

I basically tried to do the same calcs in the first 3 rows, but instead of attaching these calculations it simply returned a number in R.

Is there a way I can create a new column while performing different calculations and maintaining the same row names in the variable column? I could do mutates in dyplyr which does the same calculations (ie additions of the 2014 and 2015 columns) for every row, creating a new column but was unable to do different ones. Same with data.table.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please give more context about what you're trying to do? (There might be a more direct strategy, for instance.) Also, is the choice of which calculation goes into the `Bundled` column based on the value in `variable`, or is that based on the row position? Do you always have four rows? etc. etc.

Comment: For more context, the row 1 and row 2 for variables a and b represent counts. For example, in the 2014 column corresponding to say, variable "a", it represents a count of 3 and for 2015, the count is 4. So in the bundled column, I simply wish to add these counts. Row 3 for variable c represents the proportion of counts. For row 4 for variable d is a completely separate calculation. The choice of which calculation goes into the Bundled column is based on the variable. I have multiple rows that involve similar calculations. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more reliable approach would be to create the columns you need (in this case the sums from the first two rows, used in the third), and then use something like `dplyr::case_when` to trigger different calculations per row:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(sums = X2014 + X2015) %>%
  mutate(Bundled = case_when(variable %in% c("a", "b") ~ sums * 1.0,
                             variable == "c"   ~ lag(sums,2) / lag(sums),
                             TRUE ~ (lag(X2014,3) * X2014 +
                                     lag(X2015,3) * X2015) / 7)) %>%
  select(-sums)

> df2
  variable X2014 X2015  Bundled
1        a     3     4 7.000000
2        b     2     1 3.000000
3        c     0     3 2.333333
4        d     2     3 2.571429
```

(Note, this is based on slightly modified input to avoid having numeric-named columns.)

```
# data used above:
df <- structure(list(variable = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), X2014 = c(3L, 
2L, 0L, 2L), X2015 = c(4L, 1L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("variable", 
"X2014", "X2015"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```